# ListViewItems Animation no longer working

Tags: xaml, listview, animation, windows-runtime

I have a ListView in my XAML that contains multiple thumbnail images, after selecting some pictures with a Picker. My issue is that, I have changed the item panel template like below, and now the animations for adding of deleting an item, simply won't work. The items just pop in or disappear...

Here's how my ListView look like :

```
<ListView x:Name="ThumbnailsListView"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
          SelectionMode="Multiple"
          SelectionChanged="OnThumbnailsSelectionChanged">
          <ListView.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" >
                      <WrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
                          <TransitionCollection>
                              <ContentThemeTransition/>
                          </TransitionCollection>
                       </WrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
                   </WrapGrid>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

What could be wrong? If I cut down the part with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` the animations are OK but the visual effect is not the one desired.
I wish that items would fill the panel horizontally and then proceed to the next line.

Comment: Do you remember how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get other transitions in your `ChildrenTransitions` collection, like `AddDeleteThemeTransition`.

Comment: I tried out every transition, and it still doesn't work, each time I add a new item or delete one from my vm, the items just disappear or appear with no animation...

Comment: I guess it's also a matter of time-consuming operation? I'm selecting the files, then creating the thumbnail images and a writeablebitmap associated... I've eliminated the ChildrenTransitions and now there's animation for the entire group of items added. Not really what I wanted, but I guess I have no other way...

Comment: Do you get the animations when you remove the entire ItemsPanel definition? If not then perhaps the transition runs before the image loads.

Comment: Yes I still have the animations if I remove the entire ItemPanel definition. But if I do that, then I'll get to have a ListView with items stacked on a column, I actually wanted sort of a Gridview but with items to be arranged on rows first, not columns like a standard Gridview consists of. So, in this case, could you provide me any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You can just use a `GridView` and change the `ItemsPanel` to a `WrapGrid` with desired orientation. `AddDeleteThemeTransition` should work as a transition for what you are missing. If it doesn't play it might be because of performance issues (image loads only after transition is complete or almost complete). One more possible problem is your `Image` controls don't have a predefined `Width`/`Height`. In such cases some transitions might not work.

Comment: They are default thumbnails, created at 190x130. I'll try with setting the width/height and the tips, you gave me, if all this doesn't work, I'll stick to what I have. Thank you very much.